# Proper Service to Use for Silverlight/JavaScript

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, silverlight, model-view-controller

We're starting a new large project at work, and intend to do the UI in silverlight.  We'd like to be able to switch to HTML/JQuery later without re-writing the entire service endpoint.

What would be the standard approach to this in the Microsoft Service Stack?

Forgive the breadth of this question.  I'm new to Silverlight.

My inclination is to lean towards RESTFul JSON, which I already know how to do with MVC controllers pretty well.  But Silverlight seems to want (require?) WCF Services.  I looked at AJAX-Enabled WCF Services, but the intent there seems to be Webforms/ScriptManager.

Please point me in the right direction.  The end goal is to have a single service endpoint that can support both JavaScript and Silverlight clients.  If there is not a relatively simple solution, that is a fine answer as well.

Thanks!

Comment: What keeps you from creating two very thin frontend services?  A svc file using wcf for Silverlight and then a thin controller for jquery.  Then have both thin services call some underlying common class which houses all the logic?

Comment: @JamesF - Nothing, per se.  But it seems convoluted to do so.  I should be able to build a well-constructed, standards compliant service endpoint and consume it with both clients, or so it stands to reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can call a json ashx service using Silverlight.

You can use WebClient to make a call to a json service and receive a stream.
You can then use JsonValue and JsonArray to retrieve the data from the stream and put it into your Silverlight models.

Note:Make sure to add System.Json as a reference.

```
public void CallJson()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += ReadCompleted;
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://thisIsWhereYour.Uru/Goes.ashx"));
}

void ReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    JsonArray array = (JsonArray)JsonValue.Load(e.Result);
    foreach (var jsonPerson in array)
    {
        var person = new {
            firstName = jsonPerson["FirstName"],
            lastName = jsonPerson["LastName"]
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of examples of how to manually deserialize JSON in Silverlight.  I'm hoping to get this for free, the way you do with XML services.  What I'm interested in is finding an existing convention with the original intent of using REST/JSON with Silverlight.  I can create my own workaround.  Thanks for the effort, though.